# Appending arrays of different sizes python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to append the following arrays of different sizes resulted from appending inside for loop such that all the arrays elements stored in one column:

```
s =[array([  81.0156    ,   94.8436    ,  108.6716    ,  122.4996    ,
         136.6136    ,  150.4416    ,  164.2696    ,  178.0976    ,
         191.9256    ,  370.2036    ,  384.0316    ,  397.8596    ,
         411.6876    ,  425.5156    ,  439.6296    ,  453.4576    ,
         467.2856    ,  481.1136    ,  643.8476    ,  657.6756    ,
         671.5036    ,  685.3316    ,  699.4456    ,  713.2736    ,
         727.1016    ,  740.9296    ,  754.7576    ,  990.34984648,
        1004.46384648, 1018.29184648, 1032.11984648, 1045.94784648,
        1562.33409302, 1576.44809302, 1590.27609302, 1604.10409302,
        1617.93209302, 1780.66609302, 1794.49409302, 1808.32209302,
        1822.15009302, 1836.26409302, 1850.09209302, 1863.92009302,
        1877.74809302, 1891.57609302, 2069.85409302, 2083.68209302,
        2097.51009302, 2111.33809302, 2125.16609302, 2139.28009302,
        2153.10809302, 2166.93609302, 2180.76409302]),
 array([  74.1016    ,   87.9296    ,  101.7576    ,  115.5856    ,
         129.4136    ,  143.5276    ,  157.3556    ,  171.1836    ,
         185.0116    ,  377.1176    ,  390.9456    ,  404.7736    ,
         418.6016    ,  432.7156    ,  446.5436    ,  460.3716    ,
         474.1996    ,  488.0276    ,  636.9336    ,  650.7616    ,
         664.5896    ,  678.4176    ,  692.2456    ,  706.3596    ,
         720.1876    ,  734.0156    ,  747.8436    ,  983.43584648,
         997.54984648, 1011.37784648, 1025.20584648, 1039.03384648,
        1052.86184648, 1555.13409302, 1569.53409302, 1583.36209302,
        1597.19009302, 1611.01809302, 1624.84609302, 1773.75209302,
        1787.58009302, 1801.40809302, 1815.23609302, 1829.06409302,
        1843.17809302, 1857.00609302, 1870.83409302, 1884.66209302,
        2076.76809302, 2090.59609302, 2104.42409302, 2118.25209302,
        2132.36609302, 2146.19409302, 2160.02209302, 2173.85009302,
        2187.67809302]),
 array(769.4983),
 array(783.9523),
 array(961.88654658),
 array(976.00054658),
 array(1074.80254648),
 array(1060.68514648),
 array(1533.58479302),
 array(1547.69879302),
 array(206.6663),
 array(221.1203),
 array(341.4003),
 array(355.8543),
 array(1946.70719302),
 array(1953.62519302),
 array(2007.46519302),
 array(2014.38319302)]
```

I tried the following:

```
s2 = sorted(numpy.concatenate(s))
```

but I got the error massage:

```
 all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 2 has 0 dimension(s)
```

I also tried to use: np.column_stack(s) but it did not work too.

Comment: Try `np.hstack` instead of concatenate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flatten each element before concatenating

```
sorted(np.concatenate([x.flatten() for x in s]))
```

You could also use `sorted(np.block(s))` for concatenating recursively.